# Programmatically subtract rasters of different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, raster, gdal

#### Question:

How can I programmatically return a raster that is the difference of two (differently sized) red bands?

i.e.

```
gdal_calc.py -A 'WARPED.tif'  -B 'DSC_1636.tif' --outfile = 'dif.tif' --calc = "A-B"
```

QGIS raster calculator performs this function just fine. However, the previous code returns the following error.

> Exception: Error! Dimensions of file DSC_1636.tif (7380, 4928) are different from other files (7743, 5507).  Cannot proceed

I am currently under the impression I should read in the rasters using a defined extent, created by finding the overlap as shown below, but I am still not able to make this work.

```
# Subtract two rasters of different dimensions
# Pixel coordinates define overlap

import os, sys
from PIL import Image
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
gdal.UseExceptions()

    # Use PIL to get information from images
im1 = Image.open('DSC_0934-warped.tif')
print('warped image size is %s ' % str(im1.size))

im2 = Image.open('DSC_1636.png')
print('initial image (image 2) size is %s' % str(im2.size))
```

> warped image size is (7743, 5507)
>   initial image (image 2) size is (7380, 4928)

```
# Use GDAL to get information about images
def get_extent(fn):
    '''Returns min_x, max_y, max_x, min_y'''
    ds = gdal.Open(fn)
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    return (gt[0], gt[3], gt[0] + gt[1] * ds.RasterXSize,
        gt[3] + gt[5] * ds.RasterYSize)

print('extent of warped.tif is %s' % str(get_extent('DSC_0934-warped.tif')))
print('extent of 1636.png is %s' % str(get_extent('DSC_1636.png')))
```

> extent of warped.tif is (-375.3831214210602, 692.5167764068751, 7991.3588371542955, -5258.102875649754)
>   extent of 1636.png is (0.0, 0.0, 7380.0, 4928.0)

```
r1 = get_extent('DSC_0934-warped.tif')
r2 = get_extent('DSC_1636.png')

# Get left, top, right, bottom of dataset's bounds in pixel coordinates
intersection = [max(r1[0], r2[0]), 
                min(r1[1], r2[1]), 
                min(r1[2], r2[2]), 
                max(r1[3], r2[3])]

print('checking for overlap')
if (intersection[2] < intersection[0]) or (intersection[1] > intersection[3]):
    intersection = None
    print('no overlap')
else:
    print('intersection overlaps at: %s' % intersection)
```

> checking for overlap
>   intersection overlaps at: [0.0, 0.0, 7380.0, 4928.0]

Comment: assuming both images have the same "projection" or coordinate system, and the grids are aligned ... cropping the big image with the small one doesn't give you the results you want?

Comment: @eyllanesc - Thank you for the edits. looks much better.

Comment: @Val, Not all warped images are larger than their counterparts so it is not a reliable method for a batch tool. Good idea otherwise though. Thank you.

Comment: Update coming - I think I can use `PIL` to create a new single band image, then populate the pixels with the difference of the red bands using the `GDAL` coords to look up the red band values in the two input images.

Comment: Of course you could check programmatically if the dimensions are different. If they aren't, you probably don't get the error you mention above.

Comment: ... as I just see you're trying to do with your edit. Regarding the new error, did you try calling `ReadAsArray()` directly from `ds1_bnd` and `ds2_bnd`? You can specify the window with `xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize`

Comment: @Val, this makes sense, but I am struggling to get the bands to align properly when using this method. I have to run, but I will post again this afternoon with an update. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward answer is to read in the images as an array of defined dimensions.

Without reposting the code above used to check where the overlap is, the solution can be had with the following additions. (Thank you @Val)

```
# Get the data
ds1_src = gdal.Open( "DSC_1636.png" )
ds2_src = gdal.Open( "DSC_0934-warped.tif")

ds1_bnd = ds1_src.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(xoff=0, yoff=0, win_xsize=7380, win_ysize=4928)
ds2_bnd = ds2_src.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(xoff=0, yoff=0, win_xsize=7380, win_ysize=4928)

# Do the maths...
data_out = ds2_bnd - ds1_bnd

#Write the out file
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dsOut = driver.Create("out.tiff", 7380, 4928, 1, GDT_Byte)
CopyDatasetInfo(ds1_src,dsOut)
bandOut=dsOut.GetRasterBand(1)
BandWriteArray(bandOut, data_out)

#Close the datasets
ds1_src = None
ds2_src = None
ds1_bnd = None
ds2_bnd = None
bandOut = None
dsOut = None
```